# Fields returned from EWS getItem request on Appointment are incorrect

Tags: exchangewebservices, office-js, outlook-web-addins

The add-in I'm working on makes an getItem EWS request using Office.js to get certain fields otherwise unavailable. Mainly recurrence data, the all day flag, and the the body for older Exchange versions.

Depending on the environment the fields are incorrect when composing an appointment.  Once the appointment is sent (if it has attendees) or saved (if it does not have attendees) then the fields are correct.

The start date and end date are a year ahead, the subject and body are empty when they shouldn't be, and the item class is always IPM.Appointment or null regardless of whether the it's a recurring appointment.  Saving the appointment via Office.js before making the ews request does not make a difference.  I even tried making the ews request a few minutes after I saved the appointment.

This seems to occur for some Outlook on the web users, but not for users using the Windows clients.  I tried Outlook on the web with an Office 365 account, on-premise 2016, and on-premise 2013.  Only the Office 365 account seems to have this issue.

My question is, is there something I can check, like the Exchange Server version, to find out if a user will run into this issue?  I want to prevent using incorrect data if possible.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Since you are new user, I recommend you read ["How to Ask a Good Question"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Asking question properly will help you get better answers and help others be able to understand your question if they have a similar problem. It isn't clear for example which "fields" are incorrect or in what way they are incorrect.

Comment: Updated the post.

Answer (score 0):

This scenario occurs when calling Office.context.mailbox.item.saveAsync on a new  Calendar item that has not been sent yet. We are aware of this issue and are looking into a solution to resolve this so that the API can be used as designed. The API should behave as designed in Mail and on Existing Calendar items. Note that for existing Calendar items, an update may be sent out to attendees depending on the changes that the user or the add-in made in the compose form.